# Как отличить, где определяемое слово, а где — приложение?

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

Второе тире опускается(по Розенталю):

3) если приложение предшествует определяемому слову:
*Один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны — спортсмены клуба «Фили» (Москва) одержали третью победу подряд* (газ.);
*Глашатай лесов — кукушка известила всех о событии.*

На Грамоте:
*И только один офицер — Сергей Гаврилов понимал, что...*
ИЛИ: *И только один офицер, Сергей Гаврилов, понимал, что...*

Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
Можно выделить уточняющее приложение запятыми или тире, но оба знака должны быть парными.

Вопрос: почему *Один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны* — это приложение, а *один офицер* — это определяемое слово (словосочетание)?

Мой друг Серёжа решил поступать в университет. *Мой друг* - приложение, стоит перед определяемым словом *Сережа*, тогда почему по правилу *Второе тире опускается, если приложение предшествует определяемому слову* не пишется так: Мой друг - Серёжа решил поступать в университет.

Answer (score 3):

Хороший вопрос. Разбирался я как-то давно с подобным в хорошей компании, поэтому даю основную идею тех обсуждений...

Но на самом деле тут прежде всего два момента. 
Первое. В большинстве случаев решает автор, где у него приложение и где - "определяемое слово". Здесь автор решил (и логично), что "спортсмены клуба" основное, поэтому согласовал сказуемое по числу именно с ним. Так что тут вопросов нет, что имел в виду автор. С "офицером" так не получится.

И второе. Из ответа "Справки" **не следует**, что *один офицер* - однозначно определяемое слово. Вы немножко за них додумали. Справка настаивает на том, что имя собственное - приложение и поэтому второе тире не опускается. А не наоборот, не "приложение потому, что не опускается".

То есть ответ постулирует имя собственное как приложение. Другое дело, откуда они такое взяли... Скорее всего они исходили из того, что при такой конструкции фразы личное имя одного героя не может быть главным в смысловом отношении, главным является то, что он *офицер*, "один офицер". Я подозреваю, что формального правила на этот конкретный случай нет, теоретически можно и по-другому грамматику истолковать, но уж очень вычурно получится имя собственное считать тут основным. В крайнем случае, если бы автор настаивал на ином, следовало бы переставить местами. *И только Сергей Гаврилов, один офицер, заметил..* - вот тут нет сомнения, что *один офицер* - уточняющее приложение, но фраза явно какая-то кособокая, чего-то в ней не хватает. Поскольку смысл фразы не мог измениться настолько от перестановки приложения в конец, получается, что в исходном варианте "один офицер" тоже не является приложением.

Вот только так, наверное, рассуждая о смысле высказывания, и можно отличить одно от другого, если на это нет прямых грамматических указаний.

Еще со школьных времен помню, что, к сожалению, в таких случаях учителя и учебники предлагают "подумать", что здесь главное, самостоятельно, а в каком направлении думать, не сообщают. Или смотреть в словари, что тоже до добра не доводит. Любимый пример таких рассуждений - "сторож-старик". Постулируется, что "сторож" главное, но ведь это от контекста зависит. Если это профессия во главу угла ставится, вопросов нет. А ну как это про слёт долгожителей и вообще статья о геронтологии?! Там профессия побоку, важно именно то, что он старый и мужчина. Вот тут тот же случай. Приходится каждый раз решать за автора, что для него важнее.

Answer (score 2):

***Приложение – имя собственное*** (имя лица или кличка животного) при определяемом слове – имени нарицательном обособляется, если такое приложение стоит после определяемого слова и имеет пояснительное значение (перед ним можно поставить слова ***а именно, то есть, а зовут его***):

[Обособление приложений](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/718-242_obosoblenie_prilozhenii.html)

**И только один офицер, Сергей Гаврилов, понимал, что...**

Обособляется приложение Сергей Гаврилов, так как можно вставить А ЗОВУТ ЕГО.

Обычно ИМЯ используется как определяемое слово:

Примечание. Во многих случаях возможна двоякая пунктуация, в зависимости от наличия или отсутствия пояснительного оттенка значения и соответствующей интонации при чтении.
Ср.: ***Один мой друг, Серёжа, решил поступать в университет*** (поясняется, какой именно из друзей решил поступать в университет). – ***Мой друг Серёжа решил поступать в университет*** (такого пояснения в данном контексте нет, причем именно имя собственное является в данном случае определяемым словом, а нарицательное – приложением). [Там же](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/718-242_obosoblenie_prilozhenii.html)

Answer (score 1):

Это тема нарицательных и собственных имен (НАР+НАР или НАР+СОБСТВ) в роли приложения и определяемого слова в части возможности их обособления, которая зависит от  взаимной позиции.

А. Обособление **при обстоятельственном значении** приложения (перед определяемым словом)

[Розенталь. § 19. Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111)

1) Приложение, стоящее **перед именем собственным**, обособляется только в том случае, если имеет **добавочное обстоятельственное значение**: Прославленный разведчик, Травкин остался тем же тихим и скромным юношей, каким был при их первой встрече (Каз.) — ср.: Хотя он был прославленным разведчиком… (с уступительным значением).

Этот пример имеет два  решения (с обособлением и без обособления, авторский выбор), но обратим внимание на то, что приложение относится к имени собственному (вариант НАР+СОБСТВ).

2) Розенталь:  При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире, при этом одно тире может опускаться:

если **приложение стоит перед определяемым словом**: Один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны — спортсмены клуба «Фили» одержали третью победу подряд (Газ.); Глашатай лесов — кукушка известила всех о событии;

Здесь **тоже обстоятельственное значение**, но запятой уже недостаточно для варианта НАР+НАР, поэтому используется тире.

**Б. Обособление при уточняющем значении** приложения (после определяемого слова): И только **один** офицер, Сергей Гаврилов, понимал, что...

Имя собственное здесь однозначно имеет значение уточнения, так как раскрывает содержание неопределенного слова *один*.

С точки зрения грамматики, обособленное имя собственное здесь является **приложением**. Сравнить: И только офицер Сергей Гаврилов, понимал, что... Здесь **приложением** является "один офицер".